# In Event Handling , is it able to pass this to another function?

Tags: jquery

When Clicked on the Remove Hyper Link , a Confirmation  Pop Up will be opened which allows User to take decision .

If User Clicks Yes , is it possible to pass the **this** reference  to the **yesclick** event ??

http://jsfiddle.net/2EL5R/151/

In simple my question is ,inside the yesclick event handler is it possible to use

```
var trtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();??
```

This is my code

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    //var trtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
    $("#itemdelpopup").popup("open");
});
$(document).on('click', '#yesclick', function(event) {
    alert('clciked on yes');

    //var trtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();

    $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});
$(document).on('click', '#noclick', function(event) {
    $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});
```

For example i have pasted a sample code , but in my application i am doing lot of stuff using $(this) , so dont want to disturb the functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend just using a variable to track the row like this:

```
var targetRow;

$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  //var trtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
  $("#itemdelpopup").popup("open");
  targetRow = $(this).closest('tr');
});
$(document).on('click', '#yesclick', function(event) {
  alert('clciked on yes');
  targetRow.remove();
  //var trtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();

  $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});
$(document).on('click', '#noclick', function(event) {
  $("#itemdelpopup").popup("close");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2EL5R/152/)**